# How to set umask default for an user?

Tags: linux, bash, umask

Does anybody know how can I set an umask by default for an user and force them to use it?

I think put `umask 0002`, for example, in his ~/.bashrc file but if I do that, they can change umask.

Thanks ;)

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: One of the server or unix based Q&A sites like http://serverfault.com might be more suited for this Q. See the links in the footer of SO.

Comment: As an administrator you should set the `umask` for your users in `/etc/profile`. They can still override it in their `~/.bashrc` (which is usually ok since they have to write it actively themselves). If you don't want them to be able to run `umask` manually, block it (revoke their execute permissions).

Comment: umask is a builtin.  You can't change its permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a work around for it by using `/etc/profile` file.
I added the following lines at end of `/etc/profile`. It will overwrite the actual umask command by after setting it the value which you require

```
umask 0002
alias umask='echo umask cannot be changed'
enable -n umask


[root@client1 ~]# umask
umask cannot be changed
[root@client1 ~]# \umask
-bash: umask: command not found
[root@client1 ~]#
```

Comment: this is not enough. You can always say `\umask` to run the default command.

Comment: @fedorqui , I agree with and modified the answer now.

Comment: Wasn't the question about configuring for a user?