# Linux file default permissions

Tags: linux, file, permissions, default, samba

I just set up a apache server on my Raspberry pi. To make the development easier I shared the /var/www/html folder with samba.

I'm able to create new files from my computer in the Pi folder, but they have the following permission :
-rwxrw---- 1 pi pi 52 juin  10 17:54 test.php

With those permissions Apache is not able to read the file.

So each time I need to send the following command to make the file readable by Apache : 
chmod a+rwx test.php

Then my permission are :
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 52 juin  10 17:54 test.php

So ok, after sending this command, it's works... But I am trying to find the command to set up the default file permissions to "-rwxrwxrwx "
I'm new with linux so maybe it's easy to fix.... Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks a lot,
Maxime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set system wide umask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10220531/608639), [Setting default permissions for newly created files and sub-directories under a directory in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/580584/608639), [How to set umask in UNIX in a way that default file permission is rwx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40684924/608639), [How to set umask default for an user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30752103/608639), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing default permissions of the file created, you can use `umask` command. `umask` is user mask which is used whenever a new file is created.

`umask` is a three digit number with octal base. First digit decides the user permissions, second is for group while third determines the permissions for others.

`umask` value is used in inverted/complemented form though. That means to determine the required `umask` value for the permissions you want, subtract the permissions (in octal form) from 666. The result should be used as your `umask` value. e.g. if you want to set default permissions to `rw-r--r--` (which is 644 in octal) subtract 644 from 666. The result (022) is your umask value.

To set value for `umask` you can simply use:

```
umask 022
```

command.

For your case here, I think you can use

```
umask 000
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. after sending "umask 000" if I create a file from the console by typing "touch test.php" it's works perfectly with the new default permissions "-rw-rw-rw-".

But if I create the file from my computer the permissions are -rwxrw---- and so I does not works..... Do you have an idea why ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.

the solution was to change the "create mask" value to 0775 in the smb.conf file.

Maxime

Answer (score 0):

The default umask value is 0022, which decides the default permission for a new file or directory. The default permission for a directory is 0777, for files the permissions are 0666 from which the default umask value 0022 is deducted to get the newly created files or directory permission.